# How to solve this equation by converting it from non-homogenous form to homogenous form and then telescoping?

Tags: homogeneous-equation

This equation below must solved by converting it from a non-homogenous equation into a homogenous one and then use the characteristic equation.

```
T(1)= 5
T(n)= 2T(n−1)+3n+1,n>1
```

In the text and pictures that follow, I show how I solved and verified using the telescoping equation and summations. I need to reach the same answer using converting it from a non-homogenous equation into a homogenous one and then use the characteristic equation, but I am not sure what is the best way to approach this?

```
Part 1:
T(1) = S(n)
( (2T(n-1)) / 2^n ) = ( T(n-1) / 2^(n-1) ) = S(n-1)
( T(n) / 2^n ) = s(1) = (s / 2)
```

[part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4oXt.jpg)
[part 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4oXt.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Find constants $A$ and $B$ such that
$$t(n)=2(t(n-1))$$
that is
$$T(n)+An+B=2T(n-1)+2A(n-1)+2B
\Leftrightarrow 3n+1=An+B-2A$$
where $t(n)=T(n)+An+B$.

Note that the above recurrence is homogeneous with respect to $t(n)$.

By the characteristic equation $z-2=0$, we have that 
$$t(n)=t(1)\cdot 2^{n-1}=(T(1)+A+B)2^{n-1}=(5+A+B)2^{n-1}$$
which implies that
$$T(n)=t(n)-An-B=(5+A+B)2^{n-1}-An-B.$$